# Run webpack in a Google Cloud Builder step

Tags: npm, webpack, google-cloud-build

I am trying to pack a web app using Google Cloud Builder.

I already have `npm install` working in a previous step of the same build.

File `webpack.config.js` is ready to use and tested outside Google Cloud Builder. It is cloned inside the `/workspace` in a previous step of this build.

How do I execute `webpack` command as a build step?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I manage to run webpack inside Google Cloud Builder configuration script.
I had to use the npx in order to execute it using the npm docker image.

This is a step to run webpack and goes inside the file `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
# run webpack
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: 'npx'
  args: ['webpack']
  dir: '${_MY_APP_DIR}templates/react_app/build'
  timeout: 10s
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using webpack version >=4:
`webpack --mode=production --config ./webpack.config.js`

Comment: I needed the command to run webpack inside a Google Cloud Builder configuration script.